# Create UPDATE from a SELECT-query including subquery retrieving several columns

Tags: sql, join, sql-update, subquery, db2-400

I have the following SELECT query:

```
SELECT
    T3.EPSINO AS FaktNr, 
    T3.EPDIVI AS Div, 
    T3.EPSUNO AS Lev,
    T3.EPPYME AS BetMet,
    T2.Summa AS Belopp
FROM 
    M3EDBPTS.FPLEDG T3
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         T1.EPCONO, T1.EPSINO, 
         T1.EPDIVI, T1.EPSUNO,
         SUM(T1.EPCUAM) AS Summa
     FROM 
         M3EDBPTS.FPLEDG T1
     WHERE 
         T1.EPCONO = 001 AND
         T1.EPDIVI = '500' AND
         T1.EPSUNO = '73823'
     GROUP BY 
         T1.EPCONO,T1.EPDIVI, T1.EPSUNO, T1.EPSINO
     HAVING 
         (SUM(T1.EPCUAM) <> 0)) AS T2 ON T3.EPCONO = T2.EPCONO 
                                      AND T3.EPDIVI = T2.EPDIVI 
                                      AND T3.EPSINO = T2.EPSINO 
                                      AND T3.EPSUNO = T2.EPSUNO

WHERE 
    T3.EPPYME IN ('KOT', 'ULK')
```

How can I create a script to update the results I get above? I tried writing:

```
    UPDATE T3
    SET T3.EPPYME = 'SEP'
    FROM M3EDBPTS.FPLEDG T3
    JOIN (SELECT 
              T1.EPCONO, T1.EPSINO, T1.EPDIVI, T1.EPSUNO,
              SUM(T1.EPCUAM) AS Summa
          FROM M3EDBPTS.FPLEDG T1
          WHERE T1.EPCONO = 001 AND T1.EPDIVI = '500' AND
                T1.EPSUNO = '73823' 
          GROUP BY T1.EPCONO, T1.EPDIVI, T1.EPSUNO, T1.EPSINO
          HAVING (SUM(T1.EPCUAM) <> 0)) AS T2 ON T3.EPCONO = T2.EPCONO 
                                              AND T3.EPDIVI = T2.EPDIVI 
                                              AND T3.EPSINO = T2.EPSINO 
                                              AND T3.EPSUNO = T2.EPSUNO
    WHERE 
        T3.EPPYME IN ('KOT','ULK')
```

But I only get the error:

> SQL0199 - Keyword FROM not expected. Valid tokens: USE SKIP WAIT WITH WHERE.

How's the syntax wrong?

Example DB-table FPLEDG:

[FPLEDG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOWnb.jpg)

Comment: You must be kidding by asking what's wrong in your update query. Just look at syntax for any update SQL over internet and you would know.

Comment: Move `SET` under `FROM` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Iseries/DB2

Comment: Apparently DB2 does not support the UPDATE using sub-select and where, so one is forced to use the MERGE command.

Comment: @Lily That is partially incorrect, the table expression for DB2 cannot be a join or a read only view, but the set statement may contain a subselect like this `(col1, col2, col3) = (select col1, col2, col3 from ...)` You need to make sure that the sub-select only returns a single row for each row to be updated, and that the update statement does not attempt to update a row that will cause the sub-select to return nothing.

Comment: Just in case you haven't found the documentation, it is in the [knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzupdt.htm)

Answer (score -1):

```
    UPDATE M3EDBPTS.FPLEDG T3
    SET T3.EPPYME = 'SEP'
    WHERE T3.EPPYME IN ('KOT', 'ULK')
      AND EXISTS (
          SELECT 
              T1.EPCONO, T1.EPSINO, T1.EPDIVI, T1.EPSUNO,
              SUM(T1.EPCUAM) AS Summa
          FROM M3EDBPTS.FPLEDG T1
          WHERE T1.EPCONO = 001 AND T1.EPDIVI = '500' AND
                T1.EPSUNO = '73823' AND
                T3.EPCONO = T1.EPCONO AND
                T3.EPDIVI = T1.EPDIVI AND
                T3.EPSINO = T1.EPSINO AND
                T3.EPSUNO = T1.EPSUNO         
          GROUP BY T1.EPCONO, T1.EPDIVI, T1.EPSUNO, T1.EPSINO
          HAVING (SUM(T1.EPCUAM) <> 0))
```

This would be the general plan of attack, but since I do not know your data model, you are going to have to test it out and see if the subselect is  correct.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I tried but I get error message "SQL0199 - Keyword AS not expected. Valid tokens: OR USE SKIP WAIT WITH.". I then tried putting a ( after EXISTS and a ) at the end but I get the same result. I also tried delting the "AS Summa" and got the same reply so it seems to be the "AS T2" the error refers to.

Comment: Thanks, the ON clause was a holdover from the join you had in there. You are still going to have to adjust this to get exactly the info you want out of it. If you give us sample data, and column definitions, we can help further.

Comment: I can't get to it right now. It would be better if you edited the question with this info.

Comment: I edited the question and added a picture of FPLEDG.